# debconf: unable to initialize frontend:

Tags: dpkg, debconf

I'm trying to (unsuccessully) correct the timezone on my system:

```
root@102c5d7bfc0d:/# dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: 
debconf: (Can't locate Debconf/FrontEnd/.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Debconf::FrontEnd:: module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at (eval 34) line 2.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Noninteractive

Current default time zone: 'Etc/UTC'
Local time is now:      Sun Jun 15 10:15:52 UTC 2014.
Universal Time is now:  Sun Jun 15 10:15:52 UTC 2014.
```

How can I get dpkg-reconfigure to interactively ask me for my time zone?

Comment: Have you tried reconfiguring debconf itself (`dpkg-reconfigure debconf`) and making sure that the 'Interface to use` is set to 'Dialog'?

Comment: @steeldriver I ran it, but problem persists.

Comment: Did it run without errors? Does `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` still show an empty `.pm` filename or does it now say `Debconf/FrontEnd/Dialog.pm`? Can you add the output of `ls /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd` to your post please?

Comment: @steeldriver It ran and output nothing. Rucent88's answer worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your shell like this, then re-run the command:

```
sudo su -
dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```